# Data grids in HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

How can I add a data grid in a view which has sortable columns and lookups too. Is there an inbuilt HTML feature I can use to implement this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Haha, that would be great, but no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using jquery, I've had success using jqgrid.  There is various tutorials for using it with asp.net mvc on the net.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the link. see this example
http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: Thanks! As of now I am using Telerik grid, very complicated :)